# How can I set a paragraph's pid in rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I'm a bit lost here. I am working on a RoR site on Heroku that has rails_admin installed. When I look at the list of paragraphs in the admin area, many have a pid set, and several do not. I need to create a new paragraph and set the pid so I can reference it in my code, but I have absolutely no clue where I can do it.

Comment: Do you want to do that directly on Heroku ? or on your development environment ?

Comment: I'd like to do it to our staging environment which is hosted on heroku as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open rails console on the Heroku by this command if you have multiple environment

```
heroku run -a app-name console
```

Then you can create Paragraph normally with the needed attributes.

Rails admin does not change anything it just gives you a user interface to see the data in your database and a way to directly add new data if you want from the provided UI.

Comment: Thank you. Now I'm curious regarding the dev environment. What would you suggest regarding that?

Comment: I'd prefer using console all the time actually. Its easier, faster and  nothing more with UI .I'm would use rails_admin in only one case which is if the website will be managed by a non-developer.